# configuring WSO2 API manager custom authenticator and claims

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm unable to persist custom claims VIA a custom authenticator using WSO2 API manager 1.9.0. For context, I've been trying to mock [custom twitter authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+Twitter+Authenticator) and pass claims to our backend using [JWT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT#PassingEnduserAttributestotheBackendUsingJWT-CustomizetheJWTgeneration).

The authenticator looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void processAuthenticationResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationContext context) {
   String username = (String) request.getAttribute("userName");
   //authenticate 
   
   //try to persist claims
   context.setSubject(username);
   Map<ClaimMapping, String> claims = new HashMap<ClaimMapping, String>();
   claims.put(ClaimMapping.build("http://wso2.org/claims/myCustomClaim",     
         "http://wso2.org/claims/myCustomClaim", null, false), "some_value");

   context.setSubjectAttributes(claims);
}
```

I also added `http://wso2.org/claims/myCustomClaim` to the default wso2 claims found in `http://wso2.org/claims`

Examining the databases two h2 databases found at {APIM_HOME}/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB and {APIM_HOME}/repository/database/WSO2AM_DB I'm unable to find "some_value" getting persisted (even if I just grep the {APIM_HOME} directories for "some_value".

Is there some additional configuration required to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the reason, but I found the following about claims:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3016

"This was not possible before because we needed to know the tenant domain from the logged in user.However from IS 5.0 onwards this is possible since we send the tenant domain as part of the URL".

May be AM 1.9 is behind IS 5.0?

Comment: I dont think this is it: no exceptions are thrown when authentication / api calls are made